# What is special about 1970-01-01 05:30:00, the date and time when python starts to count time (when time.time() = 0)

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I wrote this code in Python:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

It gave me:
`1970-01-01 05:30:00`

What is so special about this date and time in programming, especially to Python?

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html). "The epoch is the point where the time starts, and is platform dependent. For Unix, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC)."

Comment: Yes, i guess....

Comment: You can add a parameter `tz` to .fromtimestamp - set it to `tz=datetime.timezone.utc` and you'll get 1970-01-01 UTC. The 5:30 h is your local time UTC offset.